# Serve static assets by NestJs dockerized application

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, nestjs

I am looking for a way to serve static assets generated by [compodoc](https://compodoc.app/) in a  dockerized NestJs application in Azure.
I am using `app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '\\documentation'));` to map the folder as a public folder.

*..Obviously it works on my machine...*

[image]

but unfortunatelly on azure I receive only *404*

[image]

the api works as expected:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

The static files are in a dedicated folder *documentation*:

[image]

The main.ts that bootstrap the app:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(ApplicationModule);

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true } as ValidationPipeOptions));

  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('N Playground')
    .setDescription('A NestJs Playground API')
    .setVersion('0.1')
    .addTag('player')
    .build()));

  app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '\\documentation'));
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new StopWatchInterceptor());

  const port = 8080;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Application is listening on port ${port}`);

  });
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some hacking on this and got it to go in an App Service by committing all my Angular source files along with the documentation folder and updating the Virtual Path in Application Settings.

**App Setting**

[image: app settings]

**Compodoc**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time spent around my troubles, I just discovered that I serve all my content on http, so it was a false flag, I am sorry, thanks again